# How can I get the Substring after the Comma in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

For example

```
Heiniger, Hans   Hans
Müller, Nehla    Nehla
```

I tried this one:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME FROM 1 FOR POSITION(',' IN NAME)) FROM OBJ_R
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, other? Also, have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes I tried with Substring and position, but its not working. I use MYSQL

Comment: In this case don't hesitate to share with us your attempt. It will be appreciated my most readers of your question. We can also be of better help to you by correcting any mistakes you may have made.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
select substring_index(name, ',', -1) as first_name
```

Comment: ah no its SQL Server, not mySQL